# Wordpress - как вывести список популярных тегов (меток) определенной рубрики

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть такая функция, с помощью которой можно выводить список меток, которые есть у записей данной рубрики:

```
<?php
$post_ids = get_objects_in_term( get_query_var( 'cat' ), 'category' );
if ( ! empty( $post_ids ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_ids ) ) {
    $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post_ids, 'post_tag' );
    if ( ! empty( $tags ) && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $tag, 'post_tag' ); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Возникла задача выводить не все теги. А только 3 самых используемых. Я попытался добавить "order by=count", но не работает.

```
<?php
$cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$cat_ids = get_term_children( $cat, 'category' );
array_push( $cat_ids, $cat );
$post_ids = get_objects_in_term( $cat_ids, 'category' );
if ( ! empty( $post_ids ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_ids ) ) {
    $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post_ids, 'post_tag', $args = array(
    'orderby'                   => 'count', 
                      'number' =>  '3',
) );
    if ( ! empty( $tags ) && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
?>
    <ol class="top">
    <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $tag, 'post_tag' ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ol>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Comment: А все остальное работает? Подкатегории  определяются корректно? А список постов для этих подкатегорий тоже нормально выгружается?

Comment: Да, всё остальное работает. Потому что стандартное, из коробки)